# State tax refund different from what's indicated on Turbotax form

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, state-income-tax

I am digging into a past year's Utah tax return (due to an audit) and I see that 
`42 TOTAL DUE - PAY THIS AMOUNT` is over $500; I used Turbotax and I'm seeing that on my downloaded, filed tax form.

However, I see a `UT Refund` of a couple hundred dollars for that year, and I do see that refund in my old bank statements.

What gives? My memory fails me.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct year? Remember the 2016 tax form was  submitted in 2017.

Comment: Yes, double-checked the year. Strangely, the Audit Department is asking for the exact `UT Refund` amount back. The only explanation I can find was it was a Turbotax bug that caused my return to be incorrectly filed. I figure it would cost me a couple hundred dollars for a CPA to investigate and get to the bottom of this, so I decided to just pay the audit.